# what i should use "is" or "has been"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I'm writing a dossier in which I have to refer a document in one section. To avoid any grammatical mistake, I'm needlessly obsessing over each line. Can any body help me to identify which line is more suitable or grammatically correct between the following? and why?
**The Declaration of Conformity is provided in Annexure O**
or
**The Declaration of Conformity has been provided in Annexure O**

personally i feel like former is more appropriate.

Comment: In this context, "is provided" is natural and sounds like the writer did it. "...has been provided..." sounds like someone else may have provided it and the writer is just reporting that someone provided it.